# Visual Studio: Html files generate ResX errors

Tags: html, visual-studio, intellisense, resx

In my project I have a lot of html files. For each file IntelliSense reports errors about invalid ResX input (not always, for example when I switch branches. After reopen solution all errors are gone)

Example errors:

```
ResX input is not valid. Cannot find valid "resheader" tags for the ResX reader and writer type names.
ResX file Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: input. Line 2, position 1. cannot be parsed.
ResX file There are multiple root elements. Line 9, position 2. cannot be parsed.
ResX file The 'input' start tag on line 31 position 12 does not match the end tag of 'form-control'. Line 36, position 11. cannot be parsed.
```

Files does not have set `Custom Tool` neither `Custom Tool Namespace` and whole directory has set `Build Action` = `None` and `Copy to output Directory` = `Do not copy`

Is it possible to ignore html files for ResX validator?

- Visual Studio Enterprise 15.8.4

Comment: Could you share a simple project using one drive? So we could really repro this issue in our side. As you said that you switch branches, which version control tool did you use? Maybe it is related to your code format or error:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390447/c-sharp-resx-file-error and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39670230/wpf-invalid-resx-file-resx-input-is-not-valid, anyway, if possible, please share us a sample, so we could debug it in our side.

Comment: I will try to extract sample from my current project but not till the weekend